# Считается ли соединение Socket.io закрытым?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, websocket, сокет

Например, открыты 5 страниц сайта, вкладки или отдельные страницы в одном браузере.
Клиент и сервер обмениваются пакетами для поддержания (установления) связи.
В моем случае это Node.js + socket.io.

Будет ли считаться, что соединение разорвано с клиентом, если будет закрыта одна вкладка браузера (страница)?

Вопрос в том, как определить, что пользователь закрыл браузер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При отключении пользователя всегда будет выполнятся on('disconnect')

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    //Действие которое выполняется
});
```

В документации это есть: [docs](http://socket.io/docs/)